# insert into and select

Tags: select, insert

how would the query on:
Update the field `total_horas` with the hours worked on each project

I have:

```
insert into proyecto(total_horas)
select trabaja.nhoras 
from trabaja;
```

But it's trying to insert in the first firld of "`proyecto`" instead on the field "`total_horas`"

my table:

```
CREATE TABLE proyecto (
  cdpro CHAR(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre VARCHAR(30),
  coddep CHAR(2),
  FOREIGN KEY (coddep)
    REFERENCES departamento(cddep)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

also altered with:    `alter table proyecto ADD total_horas char` ;

Comment: CREATE TABLE proyecto (
  cdpro CHAR(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre VARCHAR(30),
  coddep CHAR(2),
  FOREIGN KEY (coddep)
    REFERENCES departamento(cddep)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
);              also: alter table proyecto ADD total_horas char ;

Comment: Edit your post to add that, don't just put in in a comment.

Comment: So im trying to insert into the new table that I added the valors from trabaja.nhoras , but instead of going on the field total_horas its going to cdpro.

Comment: What database are you using? Are you actually trying to insert or update?

Comment: the word translated would be update, but teacher keep saying its insert and he wont give tips.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a where condition in select statement.And please elaborate you question. `trabaja.nhoras` is the column name and you are selecting it from table `trabaja`

Example:

```
INSERT INTO proyecto
(total_horas)
SELECT trabaja.nhoras
FROM trabaja
WHERE 'condition' = 'some condition';
```